# Returning React State Array Mapping Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a webapp which uses Solidity, Web3 and React. My issue is that I have a function in my smart contract to return two different arrays at the index submitted by a user from a form. Currently I've been able to save the two results from the contract methods call into a state variable which has two arrays.

**State Constructor**

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
arrHash: [{
  arrName: []
  arrHVal: [] 
}]};
};
```

**Get Array Function**

```
getArray = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const amt = this.state.totalImgs
  for (var i=0; i < amt; i++){
    this.state.contract.methods.getImgHash(0).call().then((res) => {
     var a = res[0];
     var b = res[1];
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        arrHash: [{
          ...prevState.arrHash[0],
          arrHVal: [...prevState.arrHash[0].arrHVal, b],
          arrName: [...prevState.arrHash[0].arrName, a]
        }],
      }));
      console.log("Val " + this.state.arrHash[0].arrHVal);
      console.log("Name " + this.state.arrHash[0].arrName);
    })
    console.log(this.state.contract.methods.getImgHash(0).call());
  }
}
```

**Render**

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.getArray} variant='dark'>get array</Button>
      <table>
         <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Hash</th>
         </tr>
         {this.state.arrHash.map((item, index) => (
           <tr key={index}>
             <td>{item.arrName}</td>
             <td>{item.arrHval}</td>
           </tr>
          ))}
      </table>
```

My contract has the following setup:

```
uint public numHashes;
string [] public ImageHashes;
string [] public ImageName;


function setImgHash(string memory _imgHash, string memory _imgName) public {
        ImageHashes.push(_imgHash);
        ImageName.push(_imgName);
        numHashes = ImageHashes.length;
}

function getImgHash(uint _index) public view returns(string memory, string memory) {
        return (ImageName[_index], ImageHashes[_index]); 
}
```

From what I've gathered I can console log the states of the arrays however when it comes to mapping it that's where the issues are. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

`const amt = this.state.totalImgs` is a state that gets the count from the smart contract.

**EDIT 2:**
The 0 in the this.state.contract method is purely to get a single line back but I am also interested in looping through the arrays to display the items.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? If u think there is some issue while mapping, Can u just console.log the arrHash in the render function and check the exact value.

Comment: There is no error that I get its more the display of the values. It prints both the arrays:
`0:
arrHVal: Array(2)
0: "QmPYbXPTt8urjQ7NxH6gcSTqasvopUHcHG94CvZw2BWPVX"
1: "Qmb4DXQ1ZgQPVda62gU698a57d6CriE7WH5Re3rRJ6ez6T"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

arrName: Array(2)
0: "first img"
1: "testing second image"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
`
But I want to be able to display the both of the array contents within just a HTML table, I've tried with having an item and index parameter but only one array would display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment i believe you have an array with 2 more arrays in it and you need to iterate over those to display its value. Currently ur iterating over the outer array only.
Try below code if it works:

```
export default function App() {
  const arrHash = [{
    arrName: ["first img", "testing second image"],
    arrHVal: ["QmPYbXPTt8urjQ7NxH6gcSTqasvopUHcHG94CvZw2BWPVX","Qmb4DXQ1ZgQPVda62gU698a57d6CriE7WH5Re3rRJ6ez6T"] 
  }];
  return (
    <div>
      <table border="1px solid black">
         <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Hash</th>
         </tr>
         {Object.keys(arrHash).map((item, index) => (
           arrHash[index].arrName.map((el,i) => (
           <tr key={index}>
             <td>{el}</td>
             <td>{arrHash[index].arrHVal[i]}</td>
           </tr>

           ))
          ))}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Correct me if your arrHash array is not looking similar to mine.

Comment: The way you've done it with the constant arrHash works. I've ended up modifying the
`{Object.keys(arrHash).map((item, index) => (` <br>
To `this.state.arrHash.map((item, index) => (` value instead and it now works perfectly. <br>Thank you so much for you're assistance!